# Getting names and IP addresses of the computers over LAN

Tags: vb.net

How can I know which computers are connected with LAN (names and IP address), using Vb.Net code?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993891/list-the-ip-address-of-all-computers-connected-to-a-single-lan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my know-age this is not possible, I know you can retrieve data about the host but not the LAN. It may be possible if it is the DHCP Server in windows Server or ICS in XP.
The best solution to offer is to ping all hosts in the local sub net. Something like ping 192.168.0-255.0-255.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    TcpClient tcpclnt;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
        MessageBox.Show(hostname);
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        //IPHostEntry myipaddlist = Dns.GetHostByName(hostname);
      foreach(IPAddress ips in myipaddlist.AddressList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ipa.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show("connecting");
            tcpclnt.Connect("ur ipadress", 8001);
            label1.Text = "connected";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```