# Please tell me how to get the IP addresses of the pcs connected in a lan using c#

Tags: c#, sockets, ip, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List the IP Address of all computers connected to a single LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993891/list-the-ip-address-of-all-computers-connected-to-a-single-lan)

Can anyone please tell me exactly how to get the list of IP addresses of the PCs connected in a LAN? 
I got tired googling it because the answers are very confusing.

Please tell me how to exactly get the list of ip addresses using c#.

Answer (score 0):

so you can select the specific address-types

```
IPHostEntry host;
string localIP = "?";
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        localIP = ip.ToString();
    }
}
return localIP;
```

Comment: Its just showing only one pc's ip address what about others?

Comment: He want's all IP addresses from a local network, not the IP of a client

Comment: ahh okay I thought you want all IPs of one PC